# css positioning two divs next to each other

Tags: css

I have this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/JsZ9q/5/

I am trying to get the div with the 'b' letters to have its left edge be up against the right edge of the div with the 'a' letters.

The trick is, in the actual application, the `left` property of the left div is not set (meaning its left position will change), and there is variable number of a characters (meaning its width will change).

Update -- i added some more divs to be more clear.  In all cases, I want the 'right' div to have its left edge up against the right edge of the left div, which can vary in width due to its content.  Also, not shown, is that the left property of the left div can vary across rows.

Comment: if i float the both left, the text in the right div is allllll the way to the right.  Moreover, the div on the right is not up against the div on the left -- they are both spaced as far apart as possible within the parent

Comment: use margins? http://jsfiddle.net/JsZ9q/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div style="display:inline">b</div>
        <div style="display:inline">a</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: Span are inherently inline:
The above should behave the same as this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span>b</span>
        <span>a</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Edit: Based on fiddler

Remove the absolute position from div's in the style sheet.
Don't put white space between the div's this includes newline (as multiple white space will be replaced by a single space but this has size).

```
<div style="top:10px">
    <!--         ^^^^^ No absolute here -->
    <div style="display:inline">aaaa</div><div style="display:inline">bbbb</div>
    <!--                               ^^^^^^  No Space here -->
</div>
```

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/sNqpP/  Where I have changed it for the first line `aaaabbbb` but not for the others.

Comment: Remove white space between the divs (this inludes newline)

Comment: taking an absolute position out of the css (the real thing is much more complicated) has me almost there.  The only thing thats left is getting the 'right' div to fill all the way to the right of the parent div. I tried specifying right: 0px but the div is still only as wide as its text is.

Comment: hm does display inline-block make it ingore left/right specifications?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/JsZ9q/9/

Add `float: left;`, replace `position: absolute;` with `position: relative;` to make this work, and set `margin-left` (or `left`) to `0`. You can ignore the `clear` attributes - I only added that for readability.

Btw, this example screws with the basic reasons CSS was separated from HTML - **HTML creates the structure; CSS provides the styling**.

At no point should you EVER use the `style` attribute in your HTML, especially since the divs have a width that is only defined at runtime and you're only running this in CSS (no JS). And finally, avoid absolute positioning as much as possible.

Comment: the real code has no style attribute.  If the parent div where very wide, how do i get the right child div to fill the parent to the right, but have its left edge aligned with the left childs right edge?

Comment: @hvgotcodes I answered the second part; I assume that you have some sort of colored bg/bg img that requires you to fill the `.right` to the edge of the wrapping `div`? If so, let me know, and I'll edit the fiddle accordingly.

Comment: no, its a div that becomes editable on click.  So having it jsut as wide as the test is no good; it needs to go as far to the right as possible, given the width of the parent.

Comment: @hvgotcodes This is the best you can get with CSS. For something that dynamic, you'd have to create unique `id`s or `name`s for each element and work with native JS or jQuery. I'm happy to help you with that if you put your JS in the fiddle.

Comment: i was hoping for a css solution.  All the research I've done indicates that its not possible; I am more than capable of handling it on the js side...thanx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Float does this:

```
.left {
    float:left;
}

.right {
   float:left; 
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Or am I missing something in your question?

If you must use absolute positioning, you need to know the width of the leftmost div. That would involve some JS. Let me know if thats your problem.

Answer (score 0):

use a wrapper for positioning: [I Forked your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwyya/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a parent object with a width in order to float child objects right next to each other: http://jsfiddle.net/alanweibel/6aGbU/

```
<style type="text/css">
.wrap
{
    width:100%;
}
.left
{
    float:left;
}
</style>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">aaaa</div>
    <div class="left">bbbb</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle update was quite different, but you can get the same results as I previously stated. The parent div must have a width in order for floats to be right next to each other. Also, if you want to use the 'top' css value, make sure you have a 'position' value along with it: http://jsfiddle.net/alanweibel/6aGbU/1/